# jQuery: test if element is first of MATCHED elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several divs that are alerts. The user dismisses them and after the final one (which is the FIRST in the DOM) I need to trigger some jquery magic.

Here's some simplified HTML:

```
​<body>
<div class="">Bla bla bla</div>
<div class="alert">A</div>
<div class="alert">B</div>
</body>​
```

Here's what I'm trying to do with jquery...

```
$(".alert").click( function() {

if ( $(this).is(".alert:first") ) { 
//do stuff
}

});
```

It doesn't work. The conditional never returns true. The only way I can get it to work is using `.index()` but that sucks because if the order of the markup changes it will break the script.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: The solution uses `.index()` but in a way that I did not realize was possible. It *is* relative to the matched selection if used in that way. Thanks!

Comment: `$(.alert).click( function() {` - missing quotes around `.alert`

Comment: That was a typo. It's correct in my code. Thanks

Comment: Won't using `:first` change just like `.index()` if you alter your html?

Comment: No. It shouldn't because `:first` SHOULD be relative to the other matched elements (not the surrounding divs).

Comment: This would do it; `$(this).is($(".alert:first"))`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can code:

```
$(".alert").click(function() {
    if ($(".alert").index(this) == 0) {
       // 
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g2gGa/

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead :

```
if ($(this).hasClass("alert") && $(this).is(":first")) { 
  //do stuff
}
```

Alternately :

```
$(".alert").click( function() {
    if ($(".alert").index(this) == 0) { 
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

Hope this will help !!

Answer (score 1):

Try this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ue5H/)

```
$(".alert").click( function() {

      if (this == $(".alert:first")[0] ) { 
        //do stuff 
           alert(this);
       }

});​
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
$('.alert').click( function() {

if ( ($(this)[0] === $('.alert').first()[0])) { 
alert('first');
}

});​
```